# How do I display an attribute on product view page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, php, price

I am trying to display some attributes on the product view page on a magento 2 website. However i am not able to get the values to echo onto the page. I have tried using

```
$block->getData('price')
```

and

```
$block->getAttributeText('name')
```

I am trying to call upon the price value and also a custom text attribute and display/use via phtml file.

Appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, the price is placed on the product view page via a XML file named **catalog_product_view.xml**

You can view it in the catalog module's layout folder:

> app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Or if you installed Magento 2 with Composer:

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

A container named `product.info.price` is created on the product view page. In the container, a block named `product.price.final` is created.

You can move the block with the `<move>` method in XML ([Move Instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_mv)):

```
<move element="product.price.final" destination="content" before="-" />
```

You can also create another block that uses the same class & arguments:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final.copy" after="product.info.sku">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

*The above snippet is derived from what is in the **catalog_product_view.xml** file.

I hope this points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I have similar requirement to show some text attribute values on frontend on product view page after the short description. 

I have modified `catalog_product_view.xml` and added my own template file in my custom theme.

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main product-shop col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.measurements" template="product/view/customattribute.phtml" after="product.info.overview">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getMeasurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">measurements</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="measurements"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/design/frontend/ThemePackage/themename/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/customattribute.phtml**

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
$_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
<?php if ($_attributeValue) { ?>
    <div class="product attibute <?php echo $_className?>">
    <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have taken reference from http://www.mohannatarajan.com/magento/magento2-get-product-attribute-value

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @anshu-mishra, and only using XML (no custom template),

If your attribute is output is a number, just add the argument "at_type" with value "text".

```
<argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
```